# What is the difference between redo log and doublewirte buffer in MySql InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, redo

Before, I thought redo log was used to recovery the database when crash happened.
But I felt I was wrong when I saw the note as follows:

> #### crash recovery
>
> The cleanup activities that occur when MySQL is started again after a crash. For InnoDB tables, changes from
>   incomplete transactions are replayed using data from the redo log. Changes that were committed before the
>   crash, but not yet written into the data files, are reconstructed from the doublewrite buffer. When the database is
>   shut down normally, this type of activity is performed during shutdown by the purge operation.
>   During normal operation, committed data can be stored in the change buffer for a period of time before being
>   written to the data files. There is always a tradeoff between keeping the data files up-to-date, which introduces
>   performance overhead during normal operation, and buffering the data, which can make shutdown and crash
>   recovery take longer.
>   See Also change buffer, commit, crash, data files, doublewrite buffer, InnoDB, purge, redo log.
>   it is from mysql refman-5.7-en.pdf.

If it is real, I don't know what use redo log has. Because, when crash happens, mysql can recovery itself through doublewrite buffer. It seems redo log makes no sense. Maybe I ignore somewhere, but I don't know.
I want to know the difference between them and whether or not redo log is important to mysql InnoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this blog post will answer your question:

Click [here](http://dimitrik.free.fr/blog/archives/2011/01/mysql-performance-innodb-double-write-buffer-redo-log-size-impacts-mysql-55.html)

Comment: try to avoid **[link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)**. Links are great, but at least try to provide your original-content explaining what OP was asking about.

Comment: Thank you. Redo log helps me understand ACID features of transactions. Redo log implement or solve the consistency when crash happens. Doublewirte buffer also does. The difference is that

Comment: The difference is that the stages they process are different. modify sql -> redo log -> dirty page(buffer pool) -> doublewrite buffer -> ibdata file.

Comment: I guess I'm confused why MySQL needs to write data three times then. The redo log, the doublewrite buffer, then the data file. I would think if engineered properly, it would only need two.

Answer (score 2):

The redo log appears to function at lower more critical level.  I use mySQL as a desktop analysis tool, so I figured I don't need the production database protections. I see noticeably improved query performance when doublewrite buffering is turned off (`innodb-doublewrite=0`).  No problem with that, for well over a year.  The Redo Log is a a different story; within a week of disabling it, I ended up needed to rebuild my database.

In 8.0.21, the capability to toggle the redo log (`ALTER INSTANCE ENABLE|DISABLE REDO_LOG`) was introduced. "Why not give that a try?" I thought.  Once turned off, I saw 2-5% improvement in load speeds.

This makes a difference when loading large files, especially if the [Parallel Table Import Utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-parallel-table.html) (introduced in 8.0.17) is used.

Unfortunately, I left the REDO LOG disabled and suffered a hiccup on my workstation as I writing to tables, and ended up with this error message:

```
[ERROR] [MY-013578] [InnoDB] Server was killed when Innodb Redo logging was disabled. Data files could be corrupt. You can try to restart the database with innodb_force_recovery=6
```

I had to initialize a new instance, as none of the tables would let me write anything after I got this error.

`Force_recovery=6` is strict and read-only.  I had to rebuild my database (which mostly I do anyway every time I import tables), but a few tables of constants and history I had to restore manually.

[This is documented on the mySQL page Redo Log documentation page.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-redo-log.html)  The caution on redo log gets a shaded boldfaece warning callout.   I should have listened to it.

I still disable the redo log, but only from inside the .js code that runs the parallel import utility:

```
\sql
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;
ALTER INSTANCE DISABLE INNODB REDO_LOG;
```

I leave it enabled in code, always. I leave the doublewrite buffer off, as any transactions rendered partial I can easily correct by reloading the table.